# Word for "someone who doesn't want you to succeed"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a word for *someone who doesn't want you to succeed* or *threatened by your success*.

Particular for fear that your success will overshadow their own. Not so much for malicious reasons, but more from insecurity.

Comment: My Point-Haired Boss? :)

Comment: @Affable Geek, I don't understand.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: Pointy-Haired Boss (PHB for short) is a **Dilbert** reference.

Comment: Gotcha. Missed the critical *y*.

Answer (score 3):

Someone suffering from *tall poppy syndrome*.

> Tall poppy syndrome (TPS) is a pejorative term primarily used in the UK, Canada, Australia, New Zealand and other Anglosphere nations to describe a social phenomenon in which people of genuine merit are resented, attacked, cut down, or criticised because their talents or achievements elevate them above or distinguish them from their peers.

eg.

> Sue was suffering from tall poppy syndrome. After her cousin Kathy
>   landed a high paying modeling job in New York, she complained loudly
>   at the family gathering about how 'Kathy thinks she's so much better
>   than us now that she's working in New York. Pity it's not going to
>   make her an any nicer person'.

Comment: Interesting. This is the closest so far. However, not exactly it.

Answer (score 2):

How about Rival? Adversary? Frenemy? Hater?

Shadenfriend?

Comment: Frenemy is closest of the three. But as noted, it's not coming from *dislike*, more their own insecurity.

Comment: Do you mean *schadenfreude*? Seems focused on misfortune.

Comment: "Shadenfriend" was intended as a whimsical portmanteau, echoing commonly known (well, *here*) *shadenfreude*. I wasn't really intending to overthink it much, but now that you ask.... *Shaden* is German for "harm", so the general idea is that it's somebody who is a friend to you only when things are going badly for you, not well. This deconstruction depends on one's status being binary {good, bad}, vs. a more sophisticated trinary status {good, neutral, bad}, but... close enough.

Comment: If you're trying to imply some kind of zero-sum environment, whether real or just perceived by this other person, I think "rival" works best.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious, to me, candidate is **nemesis**, from the [Online Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nemesis):

> **a :** one that inflicts retribution or vengeance
>   **b :**  a formidable and usually victorious rival or opponent

Comment: Seems more vengeful. How does that related to *threatened by your success*?

Answer (score 0):

I think **opposition** would work well.

> Defined: a group of adversaries or competitors, especially a rival political party or athletic team.

If someone is your opposition, they would likely want you to fail, so that your success doesn't out shadow theirs.